# fwrite(): send of 6 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, laravel-5.4, broken-pipe

when i am using smtp without ssl it giving this error

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.onestopdigitalagency.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=thankyou@onestopdigitalagency.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

a month ago it was workig fine

and if I use this it send email but not to gmail

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.onestopdigitalagency.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=thankyou@onestopdigitalagency.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

and on tls setting it giving timeout error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into this problem with an email provider that upgraded their services to have tighter TLS security requirements. The error was the result of the remote connection being forced closed. In your case, you were not using encryption and it was working fine, but now they are requiring encryption and their SMTP server is closing the connection.

You could also use the tls setting if you change the port to 587. Port 465 is SSL, TLS is used with ports 25 or 587.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Namecheap hosting. Using the following settings it solves the issue.

```
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'server39.web-hosting.com';
    $config['smtp_port'] = '25';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@yourdomain.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '************';
```